# VoiceOver keeps saying "Firefox busy"

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, voiceover

Working on implementing/fixing the accessibility features of my client's website, we stumbled on the particular case that Firefox decides to set focus to an `<iframe>` when tabbing through a page, which no other browser does. The client then suggested that the `<iframe>` content be given a title attribute (in the `<head>` of the loaded HTML) so that the [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/osx/voiceover/) feature (and its equivalents) reads the `<iframe>` title out loud.

This works when tested in a void, as you can test here:

- http://dev.jansensan.net/tests/iframe-title-accessibility/
- http://dev.jansensan.net/tests/iframe-title-accessibility/one-time-payment.html

So in the context of the project, this should also work. However the browser keeps saying "Firefox busy" no matter what we tab onto.

What would cause this situation? I have tried [asking on the Mozilla Support forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125342#answer-884374) in the hopes of being pointed to some documentation that would provide some guidance, to no avail.

We would appreciate some guidance, in order to see if we need to change something in our content, or if this is an issue with Firefox itself.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque I am using FF 46.0.1, don't know what colleagues were using.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque unfortunately no, because I cannot publish my client's code, and when I try to test the accessibility features on their own, they work. I am looking for guidance or documentation that helps me understand what makes Voiceover say "Firefox busy".